# Embedding images in amp Email

Tags: amp-email

I was creating a amp email and, want to embed inline images using CID but amp playground throws an error

> CID is not allowe

i wonder is it because there is no attachment or i cant use them at all.

Used following code to embed images:

```
<amp-img width="1000" height="200" src="cid:${cid}" alt="progress" layout="responsive"></amp-img>
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, according to the [`amp-img` documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-img/?format=email), all images in AMP emails must be HTTPS URLs, meaning CID or data URLs are not supported.